# The order of adjective with a "pair of" something

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order

I was wondering where put adjectives used to describe a pair of clothing items.

Which is correct:

> 1. A pair of black pants or a black pair of pants?
> 2. An expensive L-sized pair of pants or a pair of expensive L-sized pants?

I would very much appreciate your answers and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

- I think both "a pair of black pants" and "a black pair of pants" are fine; the former [seems to be much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pair+of+black+pants%2Cblack+pair+of+pants&year_start=1800), but I wouldn't blink at either one.
- Neither "an expensive L-sized pair of pants" nor "a pair of expensive L-sized pants" sounds right to me, for two reasons:

  - I don't think I've ever heard someone say "L-sized". The abbreviation "L" is always pronounced 'large' in my experience. (However, extra-large, double-extra-large, etc., *are* often pronounced 'ex-ell', 'two-ex-ell', etc.)
  - We usually say "large, expensive ____" rather than "expensive, large ____" (though [the Ngram ratio is not as extremely skewed as I'd have expected](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=large+expensive%2Cexpensive+large&year_start=1800), so maybe there's some regional variation or something).

  Personally, I'd recommend "an expensive pair of large pants"; or better yet, something like "a $300 pair of large pants".

Comment: I do think it's important to say "size L" (or L-sized, not sure which I like better) instead of "large" if you're talking about the "t-shirt size" (S, M, L). A pair of large pants could be something like [pants big enough for two people](https://files2.coloribus.com/files/adsarchive/part_1519/15195205/file/gym-large-pants-600-14737.jpg).

Comment: @ColleenV: Pants are an odd example anyway, because they don't come in named sizes (at least for adult men's pants in the US, which are the only ones I buy); but for T-shirts, I would say "size large", not "size L".

Comment: It's seems strange to me that you've never seen size L men's pants - when I [search for 'men's size L pants' on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=men%27s+size+L+pants&tbm=shop) there are tons of results. I don't know that I've ever seen athletic pants that weren't sized S/M/L/XL.

Comment: @ColleenV: My mistake. I haven't owned sweatpants in years -- I always work out in shorts -- buy I do own a pair of lounge pants, and whaddaya know, they're size L!

Comment: It's hard sometimes to notice what assumptions we're making about the meaning of certain words once we have a picture in our heads :)

Answer (score 1):

Although you will be understood when saying whichever of the two, the adjective order is specified, for example here:

http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/

That means:

> A pair of black pants

and

> A pair of expensive L-size of pants

should be the go-to expressions here.

Note that these are very minor differences and you are unlikely to come across anyone who would flinch at either one. (apart from a very malicious grammar test)

Comment: I think you must have a typo; did you really mean to suggest "A pair **of** expensive L-size **of** pants"?